# PySpark: Logistic Regression Elastic Net Regularization

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

PySpark's Logistic regression accepts an `elasticNetParam` parameter. If I set this parameter to let's say `0.2`, what does it mean? Does it mean `0.2` of `l1` and `0.8` of `l2` or is it the other way around?

Also, I have been trying to reproduce PySpark's results using sklearn. To do that I am using the `SGDClassifier` from sklearn.

This is the parameter dictionary I'm initializing the PySpark Logistic Regression model with

```
{'elasticNetParam': 0.41880231596887807, 
'regParam': 0.05816730909769129, 
'threshold': 0.4011073540317653,
'maxIter': 21.0}
```

And this is what I am using for sklearn's SGDClassifier

```
{'loss':'log',
'penalty':'elasticnet', 
'l1_ratio':0.41880231596887807, 
'alpha':0.05816730909769129, 
'fit_intercept':True, 
'max_iter':21*train_pandas.shape[0]}
```

Are these two parameter dictionary equivalent? Or should I change `l1_ratio` to `(1-0.41880231596887807)`?

Regarding `max_iter`, I thought of multiplying it by the number of rows because of the difference in the training methods. I understand that I will not get exact results, I am looking for similar results. A difference of +/- 0.01 is acceptable. But currently, the difference is about -0.05 and I am looking to bridge that.

Answer (score 4):

From the pyspark ml v2.1.0 documentation :

> elasticNetParam = Param(parent='undefined', name='elasticNetParam', doc='the ElasticNet mixing parameter, in range [0, 1]. **For alpha = 0, the penalty is an L2 penalty. For alpha = 1, it is an L1 penalty.**')

Therefore you should change `l1_ratio` to `(1-0.41880231596887807)`.

But even then, I think you may get different results between pyspark and scikit-learn because of its `random_state` and `solver` parameters.

Comment: Can you clarify more please? I want to know if elasticNetParam  must be either 0 or 1 or it can take value in between?

Comment: It can take value in between. If alpha = 0, it is an L2 penalty (Ridge regression). If alpha = 1, it is an L1 penalty (Lasso regression). If 0 < alpha < 1 : it is an elastict net regularization which combines both.